# last seen activity not save in shared preferences

Tags: android

in first activity i have 3 button firs button go to subject list , second button show last seen activity 
Im use this for last seen activity :
in subject list for each item save number in shared preferences and when user click on last seen number in subject list call and show last activity
this code work well but when i turn of phone or app not open for minutes last seen show nothing why?
please help me

in subject list class

```
  shared = getSharedPreferences("count", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
public static int counter;
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {






    if (i == 0) {
        Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Study.class);
        startActivity(intent0);
        counter=1;
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shared.edit();
        edit.putInt("count", counter);
        edit.commit();



    }
    if (i == 1) {
        counter=2;
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shared.edit();
        edit.putInt("count", counter);
        edit.commit();


                   Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Mo.class);
        startActivity(intent1);


    }

    if (i == 2) {
        counter=3;
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shared.edit();
        edit.putInt("count", counter);
        edit.commit();




        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Sa.class);
        startActivity(intent2);



    }
```

in fist activity that contain last seen button :

```
 case R.id.last_seen_btn:

            if (SubjectActivity.counter==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " nothing",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            if (SubjectActivity.counter==1){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Study.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            if (SubjectActivity.counter==2){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Mo.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            if (SubjectActivity.counter==3){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Sa.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall use always the "application preferences" and best is to access them via the Application object. There is caching on SharedPreferences aand it's creating some issues some time.
Also update always the SharedPreferences before opening the Activity (if i == 0)

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
private SharedPreferences mMyPref;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  mMyPref = getSharedPreferences("my_pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE); 
}

public SharedPreferences getMySharedPreferences(){
    return mMyPref;
}
}
```

In your parts of code where you want to read/write just use

```
((MyApp)getApplicationContext()).getMySharedPreferences() ....
```

of of course create a local variable that gives you the possibility to work with it.

Comment: public class MyApp extends Application {

Comment: im use this but not work when reinstall app my last seen show nothing

Comment: when you update the app everything stay in the preferences but only for update. If you uninstall and reinstall the possibilities to keep this info is to store it in an external file on the sd card or on the server and "relogin"